# Android POST HTTP inside an AsyncTask class not working

Tags: android, android-studio, http, https

I've been working on a simple class with the only job to send a string from my app to a webservice.
HTTP's Get works just fine, however the Post doesn't

I'm using this code, and not getting any error messages, nevertheless it doesn't work.
Any clue why?

```
public class HTTPPostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

ECRDataFile ecrDataFile = new ECRDataFile();

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
CryptoProvider cryptoProvider = new CryptoProvider();


OutputStream out = null;
try {

JsonObject postData = new JsonObject();

postData.addProperty("id", 123);
postData.addProperty("encryptionKey", 321);

postData.addProperty("data", "Lewis' mom is fat");


URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:44378/api/values");




urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");




out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
Log.d("doInBackground Post", "doInBackground pos2");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
Log.d("doInBackground Post", "doInBackground pos3");
writer.write(postData.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
out.close();
urlConnection.connect();


}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (urlConnection != null) {
urlConnection.disconnect();
}
}


return null;
}
```

Comment: `urlConnection.connect();` That is too late. You already wrote/posted your message.

Comment: You should use an inputstream to read the message the server is sending back. And check for the resultcode.

Comment: Thanks, but could you help me with the code pls?

Comment: What you want is pretty standard and code has been published many times on stackoverflow. So search a bit. Further you are not only sending a string but a json text and your server should accept this.